# Preserve quality parameters when saving jpgs in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, jpeg

I have a bunch images, all saved using `JPEG, quality: 90, subsampling ON (2x2)`.

When saving as `.jpg` in photoshop **Save As** dialog offers no 0-100 quality option, nor a subsampling checkbox/setting.

Is it possible to preserve the quality parameters?
Using Photoshop v20.

Edit: Comments mentioned a few other save methods:

- Export As: Has a 1-100% quality option, but for whatever reason, 1% quality is actually 44 jpg quality (and 2x2 subsampling).
- Save for web: 0-100 quality. Again, 0% here is 43 jpg quality (and 2x2 subsampling).
- Quick export only allows export as PNG.

Why it isn't 1-to-1 I have no idea. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: How are you saving? Save, Save As, Quick Export, Export As, or Save for Web?

Comment: Bolded that part to be clearer. Worth noting that both Save and Save As display the same dialog.

Comment: Can't repro. I always get this intermediate panel from Save As - https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5gmY.png - might need to ask Adobe.

Comment: Exactly. And nowhere does it have a 0-100 quality slider, nor a subsampling option. The original is 90 and 0-12 does not map neatly to that - nor linearly. 0 seems to result in a quality of 64 for example.

Comment: "I have a bunch images, all saved using JPEG, quality: 90, subsampling ON (2x2)" - using what?

Comment: Where do the images come from? The "subsampling" looks lacking - it's usually expressed with 3 digits, for example 4:4:4. If memory serves right, the "File size" slider under Quality drop-down is smooth. If you want to preserve the original quality simply save them from PS with max quality and largest file size. That should retain the original quality.

Comment: Images come from the internet. As for subsampling, at least that's how IrfanView reports it. Photoshop's FileInfo doesn't seem to offer that metadata. Also this: http://users.wfu.edu/matthews/misc/jpg_vs_gif/JpgCompTest/JpgChromaSub.html and a couple other google search results also mention 2x2, so maybe that's a jpg special thing?

Comment: Subsampling in general is a jpeg-specific concept. I found [this posting](https://blogs.gnome.org/raphael/2007/10/23/mapping-jpeg-compression-levels-between-adobe-photoshop-and-gimp-24/) from the blog of one of GIMP devs, this might clarify this a bit. In any case what I said before - saving jpg from PS with max size and quality preserves the original image quality.

Answer (score 0):

Not a definitive answer, but a comment pointed out there are multiple ways to save a file in photoshop, however none of them offer the ability to preserve quality or even manually match it:

- Export As: Has a 1-100% quality option, but for whatever reason, 1% quality is actually 44 jpg quality (and 2x2 subsampling). 100% is 98 jpg quality (no subsampling). I am not sure it scales linearly either.
- Save for web: 0-100 quality. Again, 0% here is 43 jpg quality (and 2x2 subsampling).
- Quick export: The settings for this option are in preferences, but once again it goes from 1-100%, where 1% is equal to 44 jpg quality.

However I found some alternatives that allow this:

- [IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/) (free) has a checkbox when saving that preserves quality (though it says it's only an estimate). Or you can manually match it for the same effect I suppose.
- [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/) - *"is a free, open-source software suite, used for editing and manipulating digital images."* [quote]. It seems to automatically preserve the quality unless parameters to the contrary are specified.